# Are there guidelines for taking data entry in Windows 8?

Tags: user-interface, windows-8

I'm struggling to find UI/UX guidelines on how to take data from users.

For example if creating a new user should you:

- Be transitioned to a new fullscreen interface for this?
- Show a popup with the fields to be edited?
- Slide out a settings style flyout?

I haven't seen any guidance on this, would be great to see links / posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think in general a lot of the stuff in this release is geared towards making Windows a better touch-capable and media consumption oriented platform. So, you may not see too many features / guidelines around lots of data-entry related apps.

Having said that, I think the three ways you listed are among the main options you have. And I think it really depends on how important you see the entry of data to be, compared to the rest of the functionality in the app. In my opinion:

- If the piece of data the user is entering is critical to the app, and is the main thing the user needs to focus on, then go ahead and make it a separate screen.
- If the data is something that will be used to filter / change what is already on the screen, and it is 1 - 3 pieces of data, then use a pop up.
- For anything in between, I'd use a flyout style UI.

Again, the main thing is to keep in mind the UI presented is reasonably consistent with other parts of the app - so that the user is not surprised by it.

Also make sure you don't have too many text-entry fields in a touch based app - and not too many fields on one screen. In spite of a nice-ish soft-keyboard on touch devices these days, it is still a pain to type lots of stuff using those things. But these are all general guidelines you probably knew anyway.